# Get a specific key in a javascript object fast

Tags: javascript, object

Currently this is my code for getting the key that I want from my Object:

```
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(d)) {
   if (key == input){
      //do something
   }
}
```

Is there a faster way to get that key without iterating through every entry?
Thank you

Comment: `if (input in d) {...}` or `if (d.hasOwnProperty(input)) {...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for:

```
d[input]
```

Comment: That would not be handy in an `if` though, for `falsy` values.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli Hard to tell without further context, but one could of course check for `d[input] !== undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Find will find and return first element founded, so theoretically if you element lays first it will be blazing fast

```
Object.keys(obj).find(key => obj[key] === value)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for informing! Good to know where to find more information about how to create really useful answers! By the way I don't know what to add more here, this part of code is just a sample